# CodeIgniter parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in ... user_controler.php

Tags: php, codeigniter

I've been trying to run an existing CodeIgniter project that's been finished by a friend.  At his computer everything works just fine but when I try to run it on mine this message is shown in the browser:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected "[" in C:\wamp\www\P-project\application\controllers\user_controler.php on line 88
```

This is the code on line 88:

```
  $data = [];
```

This is the code for  the function:

```
function Shownews(){
                $this->load->model('user');
                $data = [];
                $data['news'] = $this->user->getNews();
        $this->load->vars($data);
    }
```

He's done it so the project URL is :

```
http://localhost/P-project/index.php/user_controler/log
```

We're both using Wampserver for the connection and Netbeans for the project.

Comment: I don't know why this question is closed. I had the same problem. It's not Codeigniter specific, but other than that I don't see why this is too localized.

Answer (score 24):

Check your PHP version first. The short hand form for the  **array** declaration `[]` was only introduced in PHP's version of 5.4 (if am not mistaken). The previous versions only supported the `()` delimiters.

So, I suggest you try changing that line to:

```
$data = array();
```

Comment: @JohnYoung: If this answer solved your problem, consider upvoting and accepting it, by clicking on the large green tick mark (✔) under the answer's score.

Comment: I have been awake for 36 hours trying to find the solution..... THANK YOU